# Group Policy to Place Shortcut on All Users Desktops

Tags: windows, group-policy, desktop, user-profile

We're looking at using a GPO to put a shortcut to a company web app on all users' desktops.
Different users are on different Windows versions, meaning the location varies:

- `c:\documents and settings\all users\desktop`
- `c:\users\all users\desktop`
- `c:\users\public\desktop`      (confusingly nicknamed `c:\users\public\public desktop`)

I can't find an environment variable for this; the most likely candidate is `allusersprofile`, but this points to `c:\programdata` (on my machine / windows 7 at least).

As such, I'm wondering what the best way is to make a GPO which will work on any of these machines?

Comment: Have you support for [Group Policy Preference Client Side Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628) on your downlevel clients?

Comment: @jscott : yes, our infrastructure team confirm we do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one GPO configuration for all types of OSs, then you must either use "%UserProfile%\Desktop" (and then the policy should apply on each user separately) or use a custom script.

Answer (score 0):

i think this topic will help you

Click here http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2014/02/17/adding-shortcuts-on-desktop-using-group-policy-preferences-in-windows-8-and-windows-8-1.aspx

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers but instead include this link along with a summary of the relevant details so that your answer can continue to be useful even if the link becomes unavailable. Your answer will actually be a very good one if you do this.